# How to translate "minister for loneliness"

Tags: translation, word-choice

Recently, I learned that the UK established a "minister for loneliness".

http://www.bbc.com/news/uk-42708507

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minister_for_Loneliness

I thought of "孤獨大臣", which simulates "minister for finance" (財務大臣); or,

"孤獨部長", which simulates "defence minister" (國防部長). But neither suit the needs. Any ideas about how to imply "cope with" into this title in Chinese?

Answer (score 2):

I think you're right:

**“孤独大臣”**

[SoHu](http://www.sohu.com/a/218690515_370262)

> **你是否也是一只孤独的"旅行青蛙"｜英国设部级孤独大臣的社会责任启示**

and

> 为解决这一问题，最近英国政府史无前例地创设了“孤独大臣”（Minister for Loneliness）这一部长级职位，由体育大臣特蕾西·克劳奇兼任。

[百家号](https://baijiahao.baidu.com/s?id=1590167450763464855&wfr=spider&for=pc)

> **英国人太寂寞？政府任命“孤独大臣”，帮民众解决孤独寂寞冷**

and

> 这个职位，就叫做“孤独大臣”(Minister for Loneliness)。

If you wanted to get *cope with* into the title probably something like

- **抗孤大臣**
- **抗寂大臣**
- **抗寞大臣**

would be more appropriate.

Comment: the problem of  "抗獨大臣" is, most people would initially think of "resist independence" 抗拒 + 獨立 :(

Comment: @水巷孑蠻 changed it now.

Comment: "抗孤" is ok, "抗寂" "抗寞" are too odd :)

Comment: hahah well they *are* options.

Comment: I would translate 'Minister for Loneliness' as 寂寞问题對策事务大臣 or simply

Comment: @TangHo I think you left off the simple part

Comment: or simply  寂寞事务大臣 ; Now I think of it 大臣 sounds too important. I would prefer 寂寞事务專員  Commissioner for Lonleiness